# Modified merge Sort Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

Describe a modified merge sort algorithm, in which a given sequence is split into split into three sub-sequences of equal size approximately one-third. Analyze asymptotically the time complexity of your algorithm. How to solve this?

Comment: See [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

Comment: @user1817250: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably your homework but i would recommend that you do read chapter 2 from Cormen , Lierson and Rivest .

solve this recurrence relation -
T(n) = 3T(n/3) + O(n)

Every problem is subdivided into 3 sub-problems and contain n/3 part of the original data. 
Apply masters theorem to it and you will find that the answer is 0( n*log(n) ).

```
Note - here logarithm is of base 3 .
```